# running wireshark inside a centOS docker container

Tags: centos, wireshark, docker

I installed wireshark using `yum` (`RUN yum install -y wireshark wireshark-qt`) - and cannot run it when I ssh into the container.

```
# tshark
tshark: Couldn't run /usr/sbin/dumpcap in child process: Operation not permitted
Are you a member of the 'wireshark' group? Try running
'usermod -a -G wireshark _your_username_' as root.
```

I tried running `usermod -a -G wireshark root` (as when I ssh into the machine, it is as root). This does not help.

Also tried `su -c '/usr/sbin/tshark'` unsuccessfully.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

`dumpcap` requires `NET_RAW` (use RAW and PACKET sockets) `NET_ADMIN` (perform network-related operations) capabilities

```
$ getcap $(which dumpcap)
/usr/sbin/dumpcap = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep
```

They  are not granted by default to unprivileged containers and must be added explicitly with `--cap-add=NET_RAW --cap-add=NET_ADMIN` when starting container

```
$ docker build -t tshark - <<EOF 
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tshark && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENTRYPOINT ["tshark"]
EOF

$ docker run --rm -it \
    --net=[container:<name|id> | host] \
    --cap-add=NET_RAW --cap-add=NET_ADMIN tshark
```

Comment: In docker compose you should add to your service the list `cap_add: - NET_RAW - NET_ADMIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I used this command and it run:

```
usermod -a -G wireshark _your_username_  

newgrp wireshark

sudo chgrp wireshark /usr/sbin/dumpcap

tshark -i eth0 -w outfile
```

Please try.

Comment: This seemed to mostly work for me on OEL7.